# How to use Form based LDAP authentication in apache

Tags: apache, openldap

Could you please tell me how to use FORM in LDAP authentication instead of the default login pop up given by apache.

Below is the apache configuration,When I access a webpage I am getting the login page but after giving username,password i am not being redirected to the requested page instead login page comes again(i have checked the ldap credentials working in the default page and it work so  no issue with the ldap)

```
<Location />
   # SetHandler form-login-handler
    AuthName example
    AuthFormProvider ldap
    AuthType form
    AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation http://localhost/login.html
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthLDAPURL ldap://localhost/dc=linuxbabe,dc=com?uid?sub?(objectClass=*)
   # Require ldap-filter objectClass=posixAccount
    Require valid-user
</Location>


   <Location "/login.html">
        Order allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        require all granted
    </Location>



    <Location /dologin.html>
      SetHandler form-login-handler
      AuthType form
      AuthName example
      AuthFormProvider ldap
      AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation http://localhost/login.html
    </Location>


<html>
<head><title>Test Login</title></head>
<body>

<form method="POST"  action="/dologin.html">
    Username: <input type="text" name="httpd_username" value="" />
    Password: <input type="password" name="httpd_password" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
    <input type="hidden" name="httpd_location"
value="http://localhost/index.html" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation of [mod_auth_form](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_auth_form.html) says at the very beginning:

> Form authentication depends on the mod_session modules

So you have to choose and configure one of the [mod_session](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_session.html) modules.

Comment: Thanks michael for your response,Now my Login page is able to authenticate using ldap but  after authentication I am able to redirect only using  input "httpd_location"  (   <input type="hidden" name="httpd_location"
value="http://localhost/app/home.html" />) in login.html page,Is there any way to redirect to whatever the requested url  is from the user    ??

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that. Especially this would require to redirect to an URL provided in user's input. You probably do not want to trust that input when generating a redirect location URL.